# How to display the count for no of comments posted on a page in plone 4.1.3

Tags: plone

i have enabled the comments in plone using "Discussion" of plone control panel but i am not able to display the count of no of comments posted in a page. I have also tried to enable comments using "Types" control panel but i was not able to achieve. Is there any procedure need to be followed to display the count of comments. I want to display the same as it is found in the plone site.

http://plone.org/products/contentwellportlets

Answer (score 3):

You can get the number of comments for plone.app.discussion by adapting the context to IConversation and get the total_comments, see :

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.discussion/blob/master/plone/app/discussion/conversation.py and 
http://plonegomobile.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1027/gomobiletheme.mobipublic/trunk/gomobiletheme/mobipublic/views.py
for example